# move files to new folders with the same name as the file?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

How can I move a group of files that share the first 9 characters of the name of the files to created folders with the same name of 9 characters

```
 example

  I have a folder containing number of files with various names each
  group    of files begin with same 9 characters ex:

  first group [HD9523587_352, HD9523587_258, HD9523587_785 ,HD9523587_473]
  second group[Hip046329_258, Hip046329_364, Hip046329_681, Hip046329_235]

  and so on
```

I need to make  new folders with the same 9 characters  of the each 
   group    then move each group files into those folders.
   thanks

Answer (score 8):

Just extract the first 9 characters to use as the directory name. In `bash`, the simplest way to do that is to use a <strike>regular expression match</strike> parameter substring expansion.

```
for f in *; do
    # [[ $f =~ ^(.{9}) ]]
    # dir=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    dir=${f:0:9}
    mkdir -p "$dir" && mv "$f" "$dir"
done
```

Comment: In Bash, the simplest way to do that is to use parameter expansions: `dir=${f:0:9}`. Note that with a regex, if the length of the filename is less than 9, `BASH_REMATCH` will be empty (so you'll get an error with `mkdir`).

Comment: Agreed, that's a far better solution.

Comment: What does ${f:0:9} do?

Comment: It expands to the 9 characters beginning at position 0 in the value of `f`.

Comment: Many thanks chepner it's exactly what i need and it's  really worked  @chepner